# Rails 3.1.0 kaminari ActionView::Template::Error inside ajax request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, kaminari

I'm trying to render my pagination links inside an ajax request with kaminari and im getting a server error. I'm using the render_to_string method to render the pagination links to a string then parse it via json. I'm using rails 3.1.0.

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Missing partial kaminari/paginator with {:handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :haml], :formats=>[:json], :locale=>[:en, :en]}. Searched in:
```

Basically it's looking for the partials in all my load paths and can't seem to find the files, and they're there for sure.

Has anyone experienced similar behavior and know of a possible reason?

Comment: Ok I figured out a temporary solution, it works when I call a separate method using a before_filter :set_method, :on => :method, then parse the rendered string as a variable to the view. Still not sure why it wont work directly in the view??

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this as well.  I was able to work around it by moving render_to_string into a respond_to block -

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js do
    foo = render_to_string(:partial => 'some_kaminari_view').to_json
    render :js => "$('#foo').html(#{foo})"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

See here: http://whowish-programming.blogspot.com/2011/07/stupid-rails3-with-missing-template-and.html

Just append .html to your view name.